# ScrollView with paging in TableView Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, scrollview, tableview

I have to create a tableview with one of the cell having a scrollview with paging enabled and paging control in it. I have already tried following.

I have created a TableView Cell in IB which has two things in it 
1.ScrollView
2.Page control and some labels placed at runtime on each page of scrollview, I have tested this scrollview and paging control in normal view and it works as expected.

I have following code in the ScrollViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ScrollViewCell : UITableViewCell<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
UIPageControl* pageControl;
UIScrollView* scrollView;
BOOL pageControlBeingUsed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView* scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl* pageControl;
- (IBAction)changePage;

@end
```

And following code in ScrollViewCell.m

```
#import "ScrollViewCell.h"

@implementation ScrollViewCell

@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize pageControl;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor],    [UIColor blueColor], nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];

        // add buttons
        CGRect Frame= CGRectMake(frame.origin.x,frame.origin.y,200,50);
        //set your x and y position whatever u want.

        UIButton *Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        Button.frame = Frame;

        UIImage *Img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"];
        [Button setBackgroundImage:Img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [scrollView addSubview: Button];

        // add text
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x,frame.origin.y+60,200,50)];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.text = @"Here you write your text";
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [scrollView addSubview:label ];
        [subview release];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);


}
 return self;
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
if (!pageControlBeingUsed) {
    // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page isvisible
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
}
- (IBAction)changePage {
// update the scroll view to the appropriate page
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
pageControlBeingUsed = YES;

}

@end
```

I am loading this cell in the table view as follows

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ScrollViewCell";

ScrollViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[ScrollViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}


return cell;
```

When I am running this app it shows an empty table with desired height but nothing in it.
Is my approach correct ? if yes whats missing ?

Thanks
Regards
Vishal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add customize your `UIScrollView` in `UITableViewCell` class itself, i am not sure whether it will work.

instead try like this in your `UITableView` class `cellForRowAtIndexPath`,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"GroupButtonCell";
    CustomCell * cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray * customcellArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for(id customcellObject in customcellArray){
            if([customcellObject isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell = (CustomCell *)customcellObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

// Customize your UIScrollView here..

    [cell.scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [cell.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor],[UIColor blueColor], nil];
    cell.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(cell.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count,cell.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = cell.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = cell.scrollView.frame.size;

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
        [cell.scrollView addSubview:subview];
    }
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: hi, its working atleast, but I am still unable to add the page control to it , I will try and let you know

Comment: my question is now if we are drawing everything in cellForIndexPath method then whats the use of XIB ? I have set the background color of tabelcell to be gray but the cell in table appears to be white what might be the reason ?

Comment: An issue but with this currently is page control doesnt change with scrolling and viewdidscroll function doesnt get called it seems it has been coded in scrollviewcell.m @Vedchi can u help ?

Comment: @vishal I posted my answer to your new SO thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910747/how-to-connect-scrollview-to-page-control-in-tableview-cell/15916886#15916886 check this out.

Answer (score 0):

try this  in ScrollViewCell.m
Inside init method.

```
       [self.contentView addSubview:scrollView];
```

You should add scrollview on cell. Check M not sure. I dint got time to try in project.

Comment: tried it but no avail, nothing working same blank cell appears

Comment: Also you should alloc init scrollView

Comment: ok thats something i dont understand being a newbie can you tell me exact possible syntax ? as the scrollview already is there in the XIB file