# How to connect scrollview to page control in TableView Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, scrollview

I have a custom cell designed with a scrollview and a pageview control, which I am displaying as follows

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"ScrollViewCell";
cell = (ScrollViewCell*)[newsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray * customcellArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ScrollViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    for(id customcellObject in customcellArray){
        if([customcellObject isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell = (ScrollViewCell *)customcellObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Customize your UIScrollView here..

[cell.scrollView setDelegate:self];
[cell.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

scrollView = cell.scrollView;
pageControl = cell.pageControl;

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor],[UIColor blueColor], nil];
cell.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(cell.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count,cell.scrollView.frame.size.height);
for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = cell.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = cell.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
    [cell.scrollView addSubview:subview];
}
// Configure the cell...
UIView* bgview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
bgview.opaque = YES;
bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[cell setBackgroundView:bgview];

return cell;
}
```

The scrollview appears and scrolls just fine in cell , but problem is page control doesnt update with the scroll, basically I want to update the page control on scroll of scrollview but since page control and scrollview both are from cell I am not getting how to achieve this, I tried implementing UIScrollViewDelegate protocol with cell and then the parent view of table view but couldnt get it working, pleas guide.

Thanks
Vishal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't place your `UIPageControll` over `UIScrollview` in your custom cell, if it is then it will get scroll along `UIScrollView` itself.So create your Custom cell like this and make outlet for each `UIScrollview` & `UIPageControll`,

[image: Custom Cell]

One change in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
// Customize your UIScrollView here..

[cell.scrollView setDelegate:self];
[cell.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[cell.scrollView setTag:indexPath.row]; // set indexpath.row as tag for cell.scrollview

NSArray * colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor],[UIColor blueColor],nil];

cell.pageControll.numberOfPages = [colors count];

And in,

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {

    CGFloat xOffset = sender.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat frameWidth = sender.frame.size.width;

    int page = floor((xOffset - frameWidth / 2) / frameWidth) + 1;

    GroupButtonCell * cell = (GroupButtonCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]]; // get appropriate cell based on scrollview tag (sender.tag).
    cell.pageControll.currentPage = page; // assigning to pagecontroll

}
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: yes my custom cell was exactly like this the things you mentioned above worked perfect with some changes, thanks

Comment: When i am scrolling , the page doesnt get scroll completely leaving previous page visible slightly , what must be the issue ? can you hint on this @vedchi ? thanks

Comment: check with your UIView frame.

Comment: i dont see any issue with frame all the calculations are same as in above code plus same stuff works fine on normal view but the page from scrollview has some offset when its inside a cell